# How to set phpmyadmin in order to run with enterprisedb apache?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I need to use MySQL, but I have installed postgres on my PC months ago.  I installed enterprisedb apache and php from postgres plugin called stackbuilder, I have done some things in my php.ini but it is still not working.

I dont need to use them at the same time, but I want to change from one to another according to my requeriments.  I already have the apache and the php from postrgres.

I have worked before with easyphp that is a combox (mysql+php+apache), but I just need MySQL.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is mysql. phppgadmin would be needed for postgresql if you want a similar tool

Comment: i know buddy, but how to run phpmyadmin using the apache of postgres?

Comment: I just want to use the apache enterprisedb for running phpmyadmin in order to work with mysql database, but this apache is too joined to postgres, the php.ini too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason in the world why MySQL and PostgreSQL can't coexist on the same machine. Ordinary php can talk to one or the other just fine.

The Apache http server itself isn't tied to PostgreSQL; you may have installed a software bundle that included both of them, but that's just for installation.

Go ahead and install either MySQL or MariadB on your system. You can download excellent and robust installers for the community ("free as in kittens, free as in speech") editions of either one of those packages from their .org web sites.

Then you may have to install phpmyadmin in one subdirectory on your web server and phpPgAdmin in another.  That shouldn't be too hard, but you will have to learn about how to install multiple applications in a single Apache instance. Hint: each app gets its own subdirectory.